# Why is my accuracy is zero after set backbone trainable?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I trained my model with frozen backbone like:

```
model.get_layer('efficientnet-b0').trainable = False
```

Now, I unfreeze backbone, compile model, start training and get accuracy closed to zero. Why?
How properly fine-tune model?

Model:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
inp1 (InputLayer)               [(None, 256, 256, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
efficientnet-b0 (Functional)    (None, None, None, 1 4049564     inp1[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Globa (None, 1280)         0           efficientnet-b0[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 1280)         0           global_average_pooling2d[0][0]   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 512)          655872      dropout[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
inp2 (InputLayer)               [(None,)]            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
head/arcface (ArcMarginProduct) (None, 15587)        7980544     dense[0][0]                      
                                                                 inp2[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
softmax (Softmax)               (None, 15587)        0           head/arcface[0][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 12,685,980
Trainable params: 8,636,416
Non-trainable params: 4,049,564
```

Comment: Did you try to train the model for more epochs than you used with freeze backbone?

Comment: Do you really have 15K classes?

Comment: yes it's 15k classes

Comment: What is the learning rate you used? How about loss value during training, did it decrease?

Answer (score 1):

Of course accuracy is ZERO.
15k class needs a huge dataset and a very complex model to learn as well.
furthermore, hyperparameters are very important like epoch, batch-size, learning rate, and so on. For instance, if you set batch-size = 1 in a binary classification, the accuracy always would be 50% (in a balanced training dataset).

you may say more about your training dataset. of course, it should be about 1.5 million if it is not that huge, you must use pre-trained models

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to train model which is able to classify more then 1k classes (see ResNet, AlexNet and etc) using approach like this

Your model backbone has already have the necessary weights to classify the your data. When you unfreeze efficientnet-b0 you allowed gradient propagation through all model. So all weights will be updated and there is no garantie that your optimizer will do it well

To train your model you need to look on learning rate, loss function, optimizer and maybe change your architecture

Comment: ArcFace loss designed for using with a lot of сlasses